# Using themed css files requires a header control on the page. (e.g. <head runat="server" />)

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on asp.net web project. When I run the project, It works correctly. But In server, I got the following error. How to solve this problem?

```
Using themed css files requires a header control on the page. (e.g. `<head runat="server" />`).
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. How to solve this problem?

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Using themed css files requires a header control on the page. (e.g. `<head runat="server" />`).

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:
[InvalidOperationException: Using themed css files requires a header control on the page. (e.g. <head runat="server" />).]
   System.Web.UI.PageTheme.SetStyleSheet() +2458406
   System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e) +8699420
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +333
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint,  Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +378
```

Comment: Could you post the full page if it's not too long?

Comment: in the master page, there is a tag "head runat="server" ".

Comment: could you change the title to something more descriptive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me the cause was missing the **PrecompiledApp.config** file on the live server since I [pre-compile](http://aspnetcompiler.codeplex.com/) sites before uploading.

Answer (score 53):

I feel none of the answers made above can resolve the actual issue faced by user if the page is not meant to render html. 
In this case, the solution is - just paste following

```
EnableTheming = "False" StylesheetTheme="" Theme=""
```

in the @Page attribute of that page.

For example, the following source code sample:

**DownloadFile.aspx.**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DownloadFile.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="WebUI.Monitorization.DownloadFile"  EnableTheming="False" StylesheetTheme="" Theme=""   %>
```

Comment: this worked for me when I was trying to make an ajax call to an empty aspx page

Comment: Yes, this was useful. My page was not an html page, it was a PDF export. There is no need to add the <head> tag if the page is not going to render html.

Comment: +1 Genius. In my case I only had to add `StyleSheetTheme=""` to make it work.

Answer (score 12):

you need a head tag with runat="server" in the page (or master page) as below

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to have just the files you need in the bin folder. If you have other dlls (old versions of actual dlls varying just by their name) strange-things-may-happen.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error as a result of a really bad copy and paste error in Visual Studio 2008. I'd replaced the page with some code scraps I had meant to email to a friend.

Despite killing all the contents of the aspx page, it threw no other errors.

Answer (score 0):

i want to extend the answer of "Suvendu Shekhar Giri".
If you have many pages that does not means to render any html and just write their reponse at stream,i.e for ajax call.
Place all such kind of pages into a single folder and add web.config in this folder.
Add the following tag in this web.config file

pages styleSheetTheme="" theme=""

Hope this will help .

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the suggested things with out finding a solution.

I am just needing a dummy page placeholder for calling LoadControl with a UserControl.
I tried setting Theme and StyleSheetTheme multiple places because System.Web.UI.Page has this OnInit method:

```
protected internal override void OnInit(EventArgs e) { 
    base.OnInit(e);

    if (_theme != null) { 
        _theme.SetStyleSheet();
    } 

    if (_styleSheet != null) {
        _styleSheet.SetStyleSheet();
    } 
}
```

I tried setting the values in OnPreInit and OnInit but that resulted in exceptions saying that I is not allowed to set those properties there. So I tried this code and found that I Theme and StyleSheetTheme where set in OnInit but not OnPreInit:

```
public BaseRenderingPage()
{
    EnableTheming = false;
    Theme = null;
    StyleSheetTheme = null;
}

protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (EnableTheming || Theme != null || StyleSheetTheme != null)
        throw new Exception("OnPreInit: " + EnableTheming + ", " + Theme + ", " + StyleSheetTheme);
    base.OnPreInit(e);
}   

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (EnableTheming || Theme != null || StyleSheetTheme != null)
        throw new Exception("OnInit: " + EnableTheming + ", " + Theme + ", " + StyleSheetTheme);
    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

I ended solving it with this hack:

```
public override string Theme
{
    get { return null; }
    set { base.Theme = null; }
}

public override string StyleSheetTheme
{
    get { return null; }
    set { base.StyleSheetTheme = null; }
}
```