# Making a POST request in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, webmethod

***Scenario:***

I have a Webmethod on server1. I am trying to call Webmethod1 in server1 from another server server2 using C#/vb.net (not jQuery) as backend processing.

Below is the web method I have on server1.

```
<WebMthod> _
Public Function WebMethod1(Param1 As String, Param2 As MyComplexType) As Boolean
    Try
    // Do somethidn somewhere and return boolean
    Catch ex As Exception
    // log something somewhere and throw appropriate error
    End Try
End Function
```

I am using Rest Sharp/HttpClient to make a post call. Below is sample code using RestClient:

```
Dim request As New RestRequest("WebMethod1", Method.POST)

Dim client As New RestClient(url)
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json

request.AddParameter("Param1", 1)
request.AddParameter("Param2", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyComplexObject))

request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
request.OnBeforeDeserialization = Function(resp)
                                              resp.ContentType = "application/json"
                                              Return Nothing
                                          End Function

Dim response As RestResponse = client.Execute(request)
```

***Problem:***

Now then, I do not have any error/exception but, the problem is that it throws InternalException 500. What might be the possible problem?

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the actual exception thrown by the server? 500 just means _something_ went wrong, but doesn't provide any clues as to what it was.

Comment: I get "Using themed css files requires a header control on the page." as the webmethod is part of an .aspx code behind.

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783545/using-themed-css-files-requires-a-header-control-on-the-page-e-g-head-runat) help at all?

Comment: No unfortunately, because i think it is a false alarm, and i think the inner problem is different.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the request with fiddler?

Comment: Yes I did, unfortunately the I could not figure the issue out. I am almost about to find a solution. If I am successful will post my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because in your web method you are expecting `string` as first argument but you are passing `1` which is not string!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked it the parameter, data types all match. As I said before the webmethod is in an .aspx page like how rudimentary webservices were done in .net 2.0. http://ServiceUrl/SomePage.aspx/Webmethod1.

I used postman to pass values and test it and I get error i.e. "Using themed css files requires a header control on the page."

Comment: it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783545/using-themed-css-files-requires-a-header-control-on-the-page-e-g-head-runat @Immortal

Comment: but my problem is not that, Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: you might require [HttpPost] attribute above method..give it a try @Immortal